# "Unable to load the requested file: search_result.php" error

Tags: codeigniter

i want create a search box , where we input student name then show all records of that students.my controller code is

```
public function search_function_in_controller()
    {
           if ($this->session->userdata('admin_login') != 1)
            redirect('login', 'refresh');
           $keyword = $_POST['keyword']; // you can also use $this->input->post('keyword');

            $data['search_result'] = $this->crud_model->search($keyword);
            $this->load->view('search_result', $data);
    }
```

my model is :

```
function search($keyword)
    {
        $this->db->like('name',$keyword);
        $query  =   $this->db->get('student');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

my view is :

```
<body>
<form action="<?=site_url('admin/search_function_in_controller')?>" method="post">
  search: <input type="text" name="keyword" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form> 
<div>
    <?php
        // List up all results.
        foreach ($results as $val)
        {
            echo $val['username'];
        }
    ?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

but when we give input on search box then it give "Unable to load the requested file: search_result.php" , can anyone help me??

Answer (score 0):

Verify the path that you've called in your view.

I think you intended to call the view `admin/search_result` in your function `search_function_in_controller`;